# Can't connect to db after docker compose up

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  product-db:
    container_name: product
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: TesT111t
    ports:
      - "443:443"
  product.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}product
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Product.Api/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - product-db
  review-db:
    container_name: review
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: TesT111t
    ports:
      - "444:444"
  review.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}review
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Review.Api/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - review-db
```

As you can see I've defined port numbers for both `product-db` and `review-db` when running docker-compose up I get no errors.

However when I try to connect to the SQL box `localhost,444` I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to localhost,444.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=10054&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I don't understand why?

Comment: Are you sure the image exposes ports 443 and 444? I only see port 1433 in the quick start guide.

Comment: When I change it to expose port 1433 I get this message Cannot start service product-db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint product (da3839731dd899d5635ea8d03c6671311649cbca76e2d5514a698b7c14bb93de): Bind for 0.0.0.0:1433 failed: port is already allocated @Ralf

Comment: Your docker host already has this port bound. Probably you are running a local SQL Server as well? So map the container port to another local port, that's perfectly fine. But you cannot change the port the image exposes. Your mappings should be `1434:1433` and `1435:1433`, or whatever other (free) host port you prefer, if you want to be able to reach the DB servers from your docker host.